# Complex derivation of a trigonometric identity

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I want to prove that $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)=C\sin(x+D)$, where $C^2=A^2+B^2$ and $D=\arctan(B/A)$. I know that there's a very simple derivation of this identity, using complex variables (playing around with $\exp(ix)$).

I know because I was able to do it half a year ago, but now I can't figure it out for the life of me. And it's infuriating... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
A \sin x+B\cos x&=\text{Im}\left(Ae^{ix}+Be^{i(x+\pi/2)}\right)\\\\
&=\text{Im}\left(e^{ix}\left(A+iB\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\,\,\,\text{Im}\left(e^{ix}e^{i\theta}\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\,\,\,\sin(x+\theta)
\end{align}$$

where $\cos \theta =A/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and $\sin \theta =B/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$